# How to set naming style in ReSharper for mspec tests with double underscore?

Tags: naming-conventions, resharper, mspec

I'm using msepc as test framework in VS 2010 with .NET 4.0 and ReSharper 6.1. I already set the naming conventions for mspec with single underscores like described in [this article](http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2010/02/11/resharper-naming-style-for-machine-specifications/). The thing is, some of my specs have a double underscore in them, so that they show up as quotation marks in my test report, like:

```
It should_have_set__products__in_request
```

or

```
It should_have_set__products__
```

Unfortunately those specs get underlined by ReSharper and are not recognized as valid naming.
Is there a way to set those naming conventions manually or some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way to do that. ReSharper doesn't allow double underscores for `all_lower` naming schemes. I guess this is the 20% case team JetBrains didn't optimize for. The plugin itself cannot influence this.

You can vote for [the issue I just created](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-288373).

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I voted for your issue. Hopefully they will come up with something.